# Reverse engineer a .NET SQL Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, assemblies, reverse-engineering

I  had a contractor who is not giving us source code for our sql assembly and I need to change something in there.  Is there any good way to reverse engineer this?

Comment: Was the contractor obligated to give you the source code?  If not, then you don't have ownership of the sources and making changes in this way could very well violate his ownership and/or the terms of your contract with him.

Comment: Most likely not just contract terms but common IP laws. If you don't own the IP you can't legally create a derived work. Just having paid the contractor does not automatically imply that the IP is yours. When you wrote 'our' assembly you are most likely referring to an assembly that you have a licence for. You need a good lawyer (or in most cases cheaper a mediator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, Red Gates [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) will help.

Legally, a Lawyer who can find out if you actually have the rights to the code and sue the contractor for it is the proper way to go.

Comment: I don't know where SQL Server stores custom assemblies. Try `SELECT * from sys.assemblies`, find the name of the assembly, and then search for it. Also check the GAC in `%windir%\assembly`, but I don't know if SQL Server uses the GAC.

Answer (score 6):

[Jetbrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) is also a **free** option.

Answer (score 4):

Telerik also has their own free decompiler [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx), but as Michael pointed out, it may not be legal to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Worth mentioning, since Red Gate's reflector started charging; JetBrains (Resharper) released [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) as a free alternative.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, there's also [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx). But check with your attorney first.